# java generics with wildcards for map

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, wildcard

I am trying to build a map, and it's values  can be a list of class person,animals or string, and then I am reading it at the end.

I have the following questions:

```
Map<String,List<? extends Object>> someDataMap = 
new LinkedHashMap<String,List<? extends Object>>();

Person p = new Person();
Animals a = new Animals();

List<Person> personList  = p.getPersonList();
List<Animals> animalsList  = a.getAnimalsList();


List<String> someStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

someStrings.add("Employe123");
someStrings.add("Pet-Cat");


// putting lists into map
someDataMap.put("person",personList);
someDataMap.put("animals",animalsList);
someDataMap.put("listsOfData",someStrings);



// now reading the values.


   Map<String,List<? extends Object>> datMap  = 
   (Map<String,List<? extends Object>>)model.get("datMap");

List<Person> dataList = (List<Person>) datMap.get("person");

List<Animals> nodalList = (List<Animals>)datMap.get("animals");

List<String> listsOfData = (List<String>) datMap.get("listsOfData");
```

1. Is this approach correct, I mean putting these values and read them.
2. Why not use a Map without parameters, why use generics and generics with wildcards, i did read about it and am still not clear

I would like to try this approach without a pojo. or Is pojo necessary.

Please help, your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use generics, you don't need to explicitly cast the object you read from the list

Assuming `Map<String, Animal> map...` then `map.get("someKey");` will return an `Animal`.

The same goes in some of your more complex examples.

The problem arises when you put different types of objects into `Map`s.  It sound like you need a POJO rather than a `Map`;

```
class Stuff {

  private List<Person> people;
  private List<Animal> animals;
  private List<String> data;

 // Getters and setters

}
```

This will be cleaner, and seems to suit your need from what I understand of your question.  Just pass `Stuff` around instead of a `Map`, which doesn't seem to suit your needs in this case.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I would like to get more answers. I am trying to see how efficiently use List<? extends Object> for a value of map with different values.

Comment: The point of generics `List`s, is that they contain the same type of element, so you don't have to cast them when you `get()` values from them.  If you need to case explicitly, you'd better think of a better solution.  Sometimes a simple `POJO` with three lists can save lots of headaches, and result in much cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is not good since the casts are not safe.  A cast to `List<Person>` will not check that all items in the list are of type `Person`.  You would get a `ClassCastException` when you try to retrieve an element that is not a `Person`.

You should
1) consider if you really need to put those lists in a `Map`.
2) if you do, you could copy the lists (if they aren't huge) after getting them from the map:

```
List<Person> dataList = new ArrayList<Person>(datMap.get("person"));
```

But of course then updates to the list would not be done in the source list.